# Selenium: Using WebElement.findElements() to narrow results

Tags: css, selenium

I have a list of `WebElements` that I iterate through, lets call the `List` graphs and each element is a graph (i.e `for (WebElement graph : graphs)` ). Each graph has some descendants, some of which are similar in multiple graphs.
So I would like to say something like:

```
List<> descendents = graph.findElements(By by)
```

to get these descendants, though currently it is also finding similar descendents in other graphs. I am using `By.cssSelector()`. There are also children of these descendents and I can use a css selector to find these children and the results are limited to the single graph but I need information from the parent of these children so I can not do it like this.

Can anyone explain why this may be happening? or is there maybe a way to first find the child and from there get the parent?

I was thinking something like: `graph.findElements(By.cssSelector(".child:parent")` but this is not a valid css selector.

If anything here is unclear please let me know.

Thanks!

EDIT_1: here is the hierarchy I am looking at:

```
<div class="graph">
    <...several nested tags...>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child" />
            <div class="child" />
        </div>
    <...several nested tags.../>
</div>
<div class="graph">
    <...several nested tags...>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child" />
            <div class="child" />
        </div>
    <...several nested tags.../>
</div>
<div class="graph">
    <...several nested tags...>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child" />
            <div class="child" />
        </div>
    <...several nested tags.../>
</div>
```

In this case using `graph.findElements(By.cssSelector(".parent"))` returns a list of 3 `WebElement`'s where I would like to only have 1 but using `graph.findElements(By.cssSelector(".child"))` returns a list of 2 `WebElement`'s... as I would expect

EDIT_2:

here is the info I need to grab:

from the parent: the class name, its class name is used as a sort of boolean value, it looks one way if it is there another way if it is not.

from child 1: it is visual, based on this boolean class name, also has a single unique class name which makes it easy to grab

from child 2: it is textual, I need the text, no ID or class name to locate it with.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are specifically looking for in the children and the parent? e.g. I'm looking for a DIV child that contains text = "abc123" and then I want to do X to the graph DIV.

Comment: OK... that helps... now please edit the HTML you have above to show the different states that it can be in... class on, class off, etc.

Comment: Im not sure how to show that, basically I need to know if the parent div has a class name or not (a boolean question) if it does I do one thing, if it doesn't I do something else

Comment: Add the actual case where the class is there and another case where the class is not... in each case. The problem is that you are only showing us one state and we can't provide a complete answer until we have all the information.

Comment: The visual child has a rect tag, the data for this tag is the only thing that changes based on the parents class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem by just using a different css selector.

```
graph.findElements(By.cssSelector("table:nth-child(2) td"));
```

returns a list of 3 `WebElement`'s; this is wrong.

```
graph.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.mar10t td"));
```

returns a list of 2 `WebElement`'s; this is correct.

It is strange because if I use the css selector search in firebug both paths give the same results...

If anyone has thoughts on why the first one is giving a wrong result please comment, I would love to read them.

Answer (score 0):

Is it imperative that you use `By.cssSelector(".parent")`? You could consider using `By.className("parent")` on the `graph` web element in your loop. You could also probably use `By.xpath(".//parent")` on the `graph` element as well. I know the Xpath isn't quite as fast, nor as clean, but it'll only cost microseconds, so that should be worth getting at the object you are looking for. The `className()` option should work, though I tend to trust the Xpath more since I can explicitly tell it what element to pull (which has proven useful to me on sites that tend to reuse class names).

Comment: Unfortunately the parent div has only one class name and it is not guaranteed to be there. I am actually using a path from graph to locate this parent, though for the child I could do this. There is another way i could implement my code that would eliminate this issue, but it is very clunky, though I would rather do this than use an xpath due to robustness issues.

Comment: There is a complicated answer to this so i will just simply say no I can not do this. Though I will say this: getting the children from the parent is not a problem, getting the parents is the problem, I need information from the parent but I only want it from parents inside the current graph, I am getting parents from other graphs. This is the problem

Comment: Could you store the parent in a temp `WebElement` and then use the CSS selector on that? (I'm just thinking that will disconnect it a bit more from your `graph` object and hopefully not grab undesired elements)

Comment: If the issue is getting parents from other graphs, using the Xpath may still be your best option. Using the .// notation (the . being the important part) should prevent the path from extending beyond the `graph` object. I'm not sure of a cleaner way to do that if the other options are pulling up parents from elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking... see if this helps. It looks like you went down this path but I'm not sure how far you went.

```
List<WebElement> graphs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.graph"));
for (WebElement graph : graphs)
{
    List<WebElement> parents = graph.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.parent"));
    for (WebElement parent : parents)
    {
        List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.child"));
        for (WebElement child : children)
        {
            if (child.getText().trim().equals("abc123"))
            {
                // found what I'm looking for... do something to the parent
                System.out.println(parent.getText().trim());
                // at some point you may want to break; from the nested loops
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to dive straight to the child that you want using a CSS Selector, e.g.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.graph div.child"));
```

Loop through those elements until you find the one you want then do a

```
foundElement.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
```

to get the parent. It's kinda clunky but it will get the job done.

Comment: This is really close, just the children do not go in a list, there are only two so I just grab the info I need from them. The problem I am having though is that when I get the list of parents I get some from other graphs; this is not good. And what I am trying to fix. The strange thing is that if I get the visual child rather than the parent, I only get the ones local to the current graph; This is good, but I don't actually need any info from this element.

Comment: With the HTML you provided and the code above, what you are saying is not possible. You can't get a div.parent from #2 when you are in the div.graph #1 loop. Make sure you are using the loop variable as the starting point... e.g. `parent.findElements()` and not `driver.findElements()`.

Comment: This is the code I have: `List<WebElement> toggles = graph.findElements(By.cssSelector("table:nth-child(2) td"));` this is returning a list of 3 elements, where it should only have 2